# How do I Convert a QSetting::NativeFormat to QSetting::IniFormat?

Tags: linux, macos, qt, plist, qsettings

Hello I have a Mac OS X plist file(`QSetting::NativeFormat`) which is generated by an application now I want to take this plist file on a Linux based OS which does not Support it. So I decided to take this file in INI format. which is easy to read by `QSetting::IniFormat` . But I confuse how do I convert a `QSetting::NativeFormat` to `QSetting::IniFormat` . Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me.

```
    QSettings Source("/path/filename.plist",QSettings::NativeFormat);
    QSettings Destination("/path/filename.ini",QSettings::IniFormat);
    QStringList  allkeyList = Source.allKeys();
    for(int i=0;r<allkeyList.size();++i)
    {
        Destination.setValue(allkeyList[i], Source.value(allkeyList[i]));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The conversion must be done on OS X, because the plist native format is only supported there. You'll need to write a some code to read the settings in one format and dump them in another. You can use `QSettings::childGroups` and `childKeys` to enumerate the settings. You can have your application do it, your you can put it into a helper application that you'll manually invoke once.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy all the key & values.

```
void setcpy(QSettings *dst, const QSettings &src) {
    for (const auto &key : src.allKeys())
        dst->setValue(key, src.value(key));
}
```

Comment: This code gives the following error    "a function-definition is not allowed here before ':' token"

Comment: @rohit What compiler are you using?